# Lie Group and product manifold

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

Let $(G,*)$  and $(H,.)$  be two Lie groups. I want to show that the product manifold $GXH$ has the structure of a Lie group. I know that if $G$  and $H$ are two manifold so $GXH$ must be manifold. What must I do?

Answer (score 3):

You have to show that the product and the inversion are differentiable in $G\times H$. This is a consequence of the fact that the product of differentiable maps are differentiable.